# caret::varImp for GLM model worked before and gives me an error

Tags: r, error-handling, r-caret, glm

I want to use "varImp" from the `caret` package. It worked before and I am unsure why it won`t work anymore. 
I applied it on a log-model.

```
log_model_logit <- glm(f_status_loan ~ ., family = binomial(link = logit), data = training_set)
```

However, I get an error

> 'could not find function "varImp"' when I apply

```
varImp(log_model_probit)
```

I also get an error when I apply

```
caret::varImp(log_model_probit)
```

I am not sure what to do about the error except deleting all my packages and installing afresh. I would appreciate if someone could help me and knows how to solve this issue.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: The error when I apply 'caret::varImp(log_model_probit) is "there is no package with the name 'Matrix'

Comment: There is a typo. The name of the first model is identical with the name that is called with varImp!

Answer (score 0):

It works when you add `scale = FALSE` or `scale = TRUE` in brackets as follows

```
var_imp_log <- caret::varImp(log_model_probit) %>% as.data.frame()
```

I am still unsure why it stopped working without it but I am happy that it is working now. I hope somebody else could help this as well. Would have saved me about 1.5 hours

Comment: Without a sample of your data, we(the community) cannot know what exactly was the problem. Please edit your question as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).